# Proguard no longer works with Retrofit

Tags: android, proguard, retrofit

I have found older questions which touch on the same subject but with the latest versions none of the available answers work for me.

I am using Retrofit in my project. When I try to assemble I get the following error:

Warning: retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient

I'm using the following but none of it is helping:

```
-keepattributes Signature

-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.http.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.client.** { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.inject.* { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.* { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.mojo.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.* { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.* { *; }
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }

-libraryjars libs/acra-4.5.0.jar
-libraryjars libs/radial-menu-v4.jar

-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.events.**
-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn org.apache.lang.**

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.example.package.network.** { *; }
```

Has anybody had this issue recently and resolved it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might seem trivial, but have you tried including this line? (If you don't use okhttp that is).

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
```

Thing is Square doesn't use Proguard internally, so while their libraries may make some assumptions of what's being used, you can safely ignore it if your project doesn't use it. I had the same issue with Picasso and this fixed it for me.

Comment: This does make it compile but as you've mentioned is only safe if you are sure you are not using the functionality. I'll mark this answer as for many people it will be the correct one

Comment: Don't forget to keep the model classes too, that's what broke it for me.

Answer (score 47):

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#your package path where your gson models are stored  
-keep class com.example.models.** { *; }
```

I have used the above proguard text for Retrofit with OKHTTP.

**EDIT**:
Nice repo to refer for many popular libraries
https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets

Comment: hey you could add a little description about your work.

Comment: For me the '-keepclasseswithmember' was important - before I added it my @Path variables weren't being substituted.Thanks ! :)

Comment: For me it worked even without -keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; } though I also use okhttp

Comment: Can you please or somebody else confirm that this will work with Retrofit 2

Comment: @Sniper: Yes. you could check this as well https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-square-retrofit2.pro

Answer (score 1):

This configuration worked for **retrofit with gson**.

```
#Using for retrofit & gson
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.* { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
-keepclassmembernames interface * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
-keep interface retrofit.** { *;}
-keep interface com.squareup.** { *; }
-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
```

***plus you need to add all the POJO classes which is used with retrofit just like below.***

```
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.packagename.your.pojo.models.** { *; }
```

***keepattributes like below***

```
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Deprecated
-keepattributes SourceFile
-keepattributes LineNumberTable
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

[A nice discussion about proguard with retrofit goes here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/117)