# ProGuard not working with okhttp

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, retrofit, okhttp

ProGuard won't play nice with okhttp and I keep getting the following Warnings:

```
Warning:com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl: can't find referenced method 'long getContentLengthLong()' in program class com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl
Warning:com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl: can't find referenced method 'long getHeaderFieldLong(java.lang.String,long)' in program class com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl
Warning:com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.JavaApiConverter$CacheHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced method 'long getContentLengthLong()' in program class com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.JavaApiConverter$CacheHttpURLConnection
Warning:com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.JavaApiConverter$CacheHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced method 'long getHeaderFieldLong(java.lang.String,long)' in program class com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.JavaApiConverter$CacheHttpURLConnection
Warning:there were 4 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
```

These are my proguard settings for okhttp and retrofit:

```
-dontwarn rx.**

-dontwarn okio.**

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.*

-dontwarn retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient


-keep class retrofit.** { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {

@retrofit.http.* <methods>; }

-keepattributes Signature 
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Could this have something to do with the changes to ProGuard in Android Studio 1.0?

I tried the answers to related questions but they only suggested to use the settings I already have.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this problem.

The warnings I encountered were actually meaningless and can be ignored.

Instead I forgot to not obfuscate my model classes:

```
-keep class com.example.datamodel.** { *; }
```

After this change everything worked fine.

Comment: Fields being renamed to `a` and `b` just isn't fun!

Answer (score 36):

This works for me:

You have to add to your *proguard-rules.pro* this two lines:

```
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }

-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
```

---

Complete *proguard-rules.pro* file will look like:

```
-dontwarn rx.**

-dontwarn okio.**

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }

-dontwarn retrofit.**
-dontwarn retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24178851/4102045

Comment: Still not working for me. The warnings are suppressed but the APK is not working correctly.

Comment: Is the APK built? If the warnings are suppressed and the APK is built, I think the problem is more relationed about how you use the okhttp library, and not about the ProGuard configuration in Android Studio.

Comment: I think you are mistaken, it has to be the configuration. The APK is built but it is not working. However, if I turn off ProGuard, it is working fine. I don't directly use okhttp, only indirectly through Retrofit.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, but I'm using okHttp directly.

Comment: user `okHttp3` now

Comment: Using `dontwarn` just hides the warning, it doesn't solve the problem. If you can't get the class references to work without warnings and without setting `dontwarn` - then you have a problem...

Answer (score 7):

## OkHttp

-keepattributes Signature

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }

-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }

-dontwarn okhttp3.**

Answer (score 1):

it works for me with this configs. use `**` instead of `*` for all sub classes with encapsulated child packages

```
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
-keep class com.squareup.** { *; }
```

Comment: -dontwarn com.squareup.** just suppresses the warnings. I can create the APK but okhttp won't work. After uncommenting line 2 the same warnings showed up again.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your proguard settings:

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.**
```

I think it's safe to assume that you're not using any of the classes in `com.squareup.okhttp.internal` since that's where your warnings are originating from.

Comment: Just ignoring the warnings lets me compile but also breaks functionality, tried it before.

Comment: What do you mean "breaks functionality"?

Comment: I was able to solve this, please see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31872274/2427585 Your point was valid though, the warnings can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody still falls into here. The required Proguard configuration is documented and maintained on the main OkHttp repository:

https://github.com/square/okhttp

Answer (score 1):

For okhttp3, [you need](https://github.com/square/okhttp) [the following](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/okhttp3.pro):

```
# JSR 305 annotations are for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

# A resource is loaded with a relative path so the package of this class must be preserved.
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase

# Animal Sniffer compileOnly dependency to ensure APIs are compatible with older versions of Java.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*

# OkHttp platform used only on JVM and when Conscrypt dependency is available.
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# JSR 305 annotations are for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

# A resource is loaded with a relative path so the package of this class must be preserved.
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase

# Animal Sniffer compileOnly dependency to ensure APIs are compatible with older versions of Java.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*

# OkHttp platform used only on JVM and when Conscrypt dependency is available.
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform
```

Answer (score 0):

**okhttp3 Proguard Rules**

Here is the correct format for okhttp3 Proguard.

```
-keepattributes Signature  
-keepattributes Annotation  
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }  
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }  
-dontwarn okhttp3.**  
-dontwarn okio.**
```